# How can I plot big sums with R?

Tags: r, graph

I have the following error when trying to plot GDP values in R:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I can't figure out how to enhance the margins or circumvent the error

edit: The scale of numbers I'm using is around 100000000000

Comment: Can you scale your values?  e.g. 1 Trillion = 1000 Billion.

Comment: That error is usually an RStudio thing, not a purely-R thing.  Make your plotting window larger (or your plot margins smaller).  In RStudio, just click and drag the boarders of the plotting area to increase its size, then re-run the code to create the plot.